# Is it possible to guide animals to a new breeding ground?

Tags: zoology, behaviour, habitat

(This is a question for a book I'm working on.)

One of the threats to some animal species is the disappearance of breeding grounds (because of the spreading human population, or for example because of ship routes).

Hypothetically: would it be possible to encourage a species to breed on another place? Has that ever been tried? What do animals do naturally - do they seek another location, or rather keep trying?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Biology.SE! I suggest you to take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about this site and earn yourself your first badge. Also, can you provide a practical example of "breeding ground"?

Comment: "Breeding ground" - I'm sorry English is not my native language and I'm by no means a scientist. I mean the place where animals go to mate / spawn (f.ex. certain eels in the Sargasso Sea, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: One example where it has been tried is with whooping cranes: http://operationmigration.org/

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you mention deals primarily with [habitat fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitat_fragmentation), which has a great impact on species conservation. A fragmented habitat will impair migration and can result in [inbreeding depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbreeding_depression). This has been dealt with [wildlife crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildlife_crossing) in various sites in the world.

[image: animal bridge]